# CSS Chrome issue

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a piece of HTML like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ca28Y/

HTML

```
<ul class="searchitems">
    <li class="filis">Build
    <div class="fidivs"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-build">
 <select id="edit-build" name="build" class="form-select"><option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option><option value="Slim">Slim</option><option value="Medium">Medium</option><option value="Heavy">Heavy</option></select>
</div>
</div>
  </li>
  <li class="filis">Complexion
    <div class="fidivs"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-complexion">
 <select id="edit-complexion" name="complexion" class="form-select"><option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option><option value="Light (PaleWhite or Freckled)">Light (PaleWhite or Freckled)</option><option value="Fair (White to  Mediterannean)">Fair (White to  Mediterannean)</option><option value="Olive (Tanned to Light Brown)">Olive (Tanned to Light Brown)</option><option value="Brown">Brown</option><option value="Dark (Dark Brown to Black)">Dark (Dark Brown to Black)</option></select>
</div>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.searchitems li {
    background: url("../images/search_play_g.png") no-repeat scroll 170px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #373E44;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 15px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.searchitems li a {
    display: block;
}
#userleftmenu li {
    background: url("../images/search_play_g.png") no-repeat scroll 203px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
.searchitems li:hover {
    background: none no-repeat scroll 159px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.searchitems li.filis .fidivs {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #78BB32;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
    left: 200px;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 210px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.searchitems li:hover {
    background-color: #78BB32;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.searchitems label {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.searchitems li:hover .fidivs {
    display: table !important;
    left: 200px;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

When i hover the left menu a div will pop out and we can see the select boxes. **In chrome i cant click on select box.** 
It is working fine in Firefox, Issue is in chrome only. 
What might be the reason ?

Comment: @Andrew its not working in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox. take a look in both browsers

Comment: @matewka the question you mentioned is using `Javascript` but i am not using it.

Comment: I know. But it explains the problem.

Comment: I'm able to click on the select boxes in Chrome 33.0.1750.117 on Mac Mountain Lion

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `min-height: auto` and `margin-top: 2px` to `.searchitems li.filis .fidivs {}` and works ok in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

```
.searchitems li.filis .fidivs {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #78BB32;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
    left: 200px;
    min-height: auto; // set this
    margin-top: 2px; // add this
    min-width: 210px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca28Y/2/

Comment: The issue is i cant select the Select box in the popup div. issue persists

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**include this css**

```
      <style>
        .searchitems li {
            background: url("../images/search_play_g.png") no-repeat scroll 170px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            color: #373E44;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 15px;
            list-style: none outside none;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            position: relative;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            }

     .searchitems li a {
           display: block;
           }

     #userleftmenu li {
           background: url("../images/search_play_g.png") no-repeat scroll 203px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
      }

    .searchitems li:hover {
          background: none no-repeat scroll 159px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          }

    .searchitems li.filis .fidivs {
          background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #78BB32;
          border-radius: 3px;
          display: none;
          left: 200px;
          min-height: 8px;
          min-width: 210px;
          padding: 2px 5px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          }

    .searchitems li:hover {
          background-color: #78BB32;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          }

    .searchitems label {
          color: #FFFFFF;
          font-size: 13px;
          }

    .searchitems li:hover .fidivs {
          display: table !important;
          left: 200px;
          top: 4px;
          z-index: 9;
          }

   </style>
```

Comment: The issue is i cant select the Select box in the popup div

Comment: Pls give me screenshot in your issue